# Перестает работать/отображаться карта при добавлении в LinearLayout компонент Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, android-linearlayout

Есть LinearLayout вертикальный в котором фрагмент карты гугл и под фрагментом компонент Material Design (BottomNavigationView). При добавлении того самого компонента [перестает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmTEm.png) работать карта (отображаться корректно). [Вот так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg8B0.png) выглядит без компонента BottomNavigationView, а [вот так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmTEm.png) с компонентом

Comment: А в коде вы ничего не меняли? Может вы забыли инициализировать карту? Само по себе оно маловероятно что сломается.

Comment: Абсолютно ничего не менял, кроме добавления style, что описано в вопросе

Comment: Странно, если ничего не меняли. Про style в вопросе у вас - ни слова. Что будет, если вы не будете добавлять этот непонятный style? Может быть в нём проблема? И не выкладывайте код ссылками на картинки - код надо текстом прямо в вопросе приводить, иначе крайне не удобно. А кто-то вообще не может картинки открыть из-за проблем с ограничениями в сети.

Comment: Картинки предоставил чтобы показать наглядно, что при добавлении style (на скрине выделил) перестает работать карта

Comment: style нужен для стилизации добавленного объекта из material design

Comment: Извините, но я в упор не вижу никакого `style` на скриншотах, которые ещё и повторяются. Приведите, пж-та, код текстом, особенно выделив текстом `style` и пояснив что это такое и зачем вы его добавили. Если проблема появилась из-за него, то на нём надо сделать очевидный акцент. Возможно карта тут вообще не причём? Вы же про `styles.xml` да? Его на картинках нигде не видно.

Comment: Простите, заработался, style тут вообще не причем. Дело в том, что когда я добавляю компонент material design (BottomNavigationView) перестает работать карта, а если этот компонент убрать то все будет ок

Comment: Т.е. у вас изначально LInearLayout с фрагментом-картой и оно работает, потом вы добавляете 6 строчек в разметку и оно перестаёт работать? А если LinearLayout  заменить на FrameLayout? На данный момент выглядит проблема предельно странной, даже с трудом верится что она реальная)

Comment: Может быть вы сможете предоставить git репозиторий с воспроизведением проблемы? Раз вы, почему-то, отказываетесь нормально показывать код в вопросе?

Comment: Может я гифку сделаю?

Comment: Не надо. Я почти готов отказаться от попыток вам помочь.

Comment: Сейчас попробую с FrameLayout как вы написали

Comment: С FrameLayout заработало, есть мысли почему?

Comment: Единственная мысль - фрагмент-карта не может работать, если не указана максимально определённо высота. Во FrameLayout это весь экран, а в LinearLayout - весь экран минус высота нижней вьюхи. В теории, может быть заработает с LinearLayout в таком случае, если фрагмент обернуть в ещё один FrameLayout. У которого будет высота  и вес как сейчас у фрагмента, а у самого фрагмента - `match_parent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переделал LinearLayout в FrameLayout - заработало